# Keyboard Latency when connecting via Azure's Bastion

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-bastion

Recently when I connect to a VM via Azure's bastion product, I experience random bursts of latency. This causes the interface to almost freeze for a split second, and then whatever key was last struck gets replicated 9-10 times. The attached .gif demonstrates this.

[image: 91492-azurelatency.gif]

**Steps I've taken so far:**

- I've confirmed that it is not an issue with my keyboard by replacing my wireless keyboard with a wired one.
- I've confirmed this is not a local issue by trying this on other devices, both PC & Mac.
- I've confirmed this is not a browser issue by trying this on the most up to date versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge.

One thing I have noticed, but can't explain, is it seems to only be happening through my Azure AD account. I logged in with a different user's account on my device and was unable to repeat the error. I am not sure if it is related, but so far it is the only thing resembling a trend.

bastion connection to CRSQLVM has been very laggy. a bunch of times. This is causing massive headaches having to go back and delete constantly. Please reference the video screenshot for an example.

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional specs/information. Thanks!
-Carter